# Automating search functionality using Selenium - Java

Tags: java, selenium

I need to automate search functionality as below:

Search string = (X* OR "Y") AND Z

On entering this search system should assert the result. My problems are:
1) How to make precedence among operators because if there is () then that should be executed and with its result other parts of search string to be checked.
2) termi* can be terminate, terminator. How do we check this and assert
3) "Stack Overflow" means the result should have exactly matched. How can we find and assert
4) Likewise NOT operator, how can we assert
Pls share with me if any kind of help you can provide.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it like you search for a keyword and there will be lot of results in the web page? Like amazon product search page? Also, I did not understand the first point. Can you explain it a little more. Lastly, it would help us, if you can format your question

Comment: Thanks for you reply A.J...Yes, Like a search engine. About the fist line, When you see the Search String you first execute the command inside bracket (), then with its result you have to again execute other parts. So here we use operator precedence concept. Example first You need to execute (Termi* OR "Claim") and with its result you will check - Result AND Court. Mainly here i have listed different Operators such as OR, AND, NOT, (), * RegExp. I have to write a code for searching a query "(X* OR "Y") AND Z" and assert the contents displayed based on the search string/query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some how managed to write code in java using StringBuffer :)

Instead of storing the result of first block and process next I have created a string command based on the searchString as below and finally fire the newly created command and verified the answer.

Like whenevenever AND comes in searchString we insert && operator and for OR || operator.

```
String[] arrSearch=searchString.split("\\s");
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        boolean skipFlag = false;
        for(int i=0;i<arrSearch.length;i++){
            System.out.println(arrSearch[i]);
            if(!skipFlag && arrSearch[i].startsWith("\"")){
                skipFlag = true;
                continue;
            }else if(skipFlag){
                if(arrSearch[i].endsWith("\"")){
                    skipFlag = false;
                    continue;
                }else{
                    continue;
                }
            }else if(arrSearch[i].startsWith("(")){
                String temp = arrSearch[i].substring(1);
                sb.append("(selenium.isTextPresent(" + temp + ")" + " ");
            }else if(arrSearch[i].startsWith(")")){
                String temp = arrSearch[i].substring(0,arrSearch[i].length()-1);
                sb.append("selenium.isTextPresent(" + temp + "))" + " ");
            }else if(arrSearch[i].equalsIgnoreCase("AND")){
                sb.append("&&" + " ");
            }else if(arrSearch[i].equalsIgnoreCase("OR")){
                sb.append("||" + " ");
            }else if(arrSearch[i].equalsIgnoreCase("NOT")){
                sb.append("!");
            }else if(arrSearch[i].endsWith("*")){
                String temp = arrSearch[i].substring(0,arrSearch[i].length()-1);
                sb.append("selenium.isTextPresent(\"//*[contains('" + temp + "')]\")" + " ");
            }else{
                sb.append("selenium.isTextPresent(" + arrSearch[i] + ")" + " ");
            }
```